# Create Temorary table into Begin and End scope- vertica

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to create a temporary table within the scope of begin and end:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
     Is_Full_Exect INT;
BEGIN
     Is_Full_Exect: = 5; - since y refers to x, x = 5
     CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StringMapBase (VALUE VARCHAR (300) NULL, AttributeValue INT NULL, AttributeName VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL);
END;
$$;
```

And accepts the following error:

ERROR 10448: PL / vSQL parser failed at 6.12-15 of source string: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting: = or <- at character 109
LINE 6: CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StringMapBase (VALUE VAR ...

I would be very grateful to anyone who can help me understand the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three errors to fix:

1. remove the space between colon `:` and equal sign `=` on Line 5
2. the comment starts with a double dash `--` , not single, on Line 5
3. to perform SQL within a SP, put the `PERFORM` keyword in front of the statement.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
     Is_Full_Exect INT;
BEGIN
     Is_Full_Exect:= 5; --- since y refers to x, x = 5
     PERFORM CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StringMapBase (VALUE VARCHAR (300) NULL, AttributeValue INT NULL, AttributeName VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL);
END;
$$;
```